# why is models.ForeignKey advantageous?

Tags: python, django

In my models I have a `Concert` class and a `Venue` class. Each venue has multiple concerts. I have been linking the Concert class to a Venue with a simple

`venue = models.IntegerField(max_length = 10)`

...containing the venue object's primary key. A colleague suggested we use `venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)` instead. While this also works, I wonder if it's worth the switch because I have been able to parse out all the concerts for a venue by simply using the venue's ID in `Concert.objects.filter(venue=4)` the same way I could do this with a `ForeignKey`: `Venue_instance.Concert_set.all()`. I've never had any problems using my method.

The way I see it, using the `IntegerField` and `objects.filter()` is just as much of a "ManyToOne" relationship as a `ForeignKey`, so I want to know where I'm wrong. Why are `ForeignKeys` advantageous? Are they faster? Is it better database design? Cleaner code?

Comment: I guess it has to do with integrity. Can you set `venue` to a value that does not exist in the `Venue` table? What happens if you update or delete a key in that table using one or the other designs?

Comment: I guess that's something to consider. Is this the only issue you can think of? It's not something that worries me.

Comment: Just make the switch. For starters, with your current approach, you're screwed if you have an accidental change to your primary key scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the most practical benefit of a foreign key is the ability to query across relationships automatically. Django generates the JOINs automatically.

The automatic reverse relation helpers are great too as you mentioned.

Here are some examples that would be more complicated with only an integer relationship.

```
concerts = Concert.objects.filter(...)

concerts.order_by('venue__attribute') # ordering beyond PK.
concerts.filter(venue__name='foo') # filter by a value across the relationship
concerts.values_list('venue__name') # get just venue names
concerts.values('venue__city').annotate() # get unique values across the venue

concerts.filter(venue__more__relationships='foo')

Venue.objects.filter(concert__name='Coachella') # reverse lookups work too

# with an integer field for Concert.venue, you'd have to do something like...
Venue.objects.filter(id__in=Concert.objects.filter(name='Coachella'))
```

As others have pointed out... database integrity is useful, cascading deletes (customizable of course), and *facepalm* it just occurred to me that the django admin and forms framework work amazingly with foreign keys.

```
class ConcertInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Concert

class VenueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ConcertInline]
    # that was quick!
```

I'm sure there are more examples of django features handling foreign keys.

Comment: FKs also typically enforce [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

Comment: Thanks for all the examples. I guess if I'm gonna be using Django, I might as well use Django right? One more question since you seem to know what you're doing: what's the best way to store a list of Foreign Keys? For example, a concert has a variable number of Band objects.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Django saves us time, let it! `ManyToMany` would be the way to go for that relationship. That's a new can of kick ass isn't it? Try a managing a many to many with integers..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have it running.

Answer (score 3):

ForeignKey is a [database concept](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-fk.html) implemented in most databases that also enforces [*referential integrity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

Because django would know what this column refers to is a table, which may itself be a foreign key to some other table, it can help chain the relationship which will produce the corresponding joins in the SQL.

Other than the normal one-way chaining, Django also adds a parameter to the opposite side, like you have recognized. When you have a venue instance, you are able to query `venue.concert_set`.

The thing that bothers me the most about not using FK and rolling your own by using the integer is that:

- You don't have referential integrity check.
- You lose out on the power of SQL. Every moderately deep query of yours will now need multiple hits to the database, since you can't join. - You also lose out on all the levers the framework provides to deal with the SQL